# Relaxed LASSO for logistic regression

Tags: r, regression, logistic, lasso

I want to try doing relaxed LASSO on some of my data, and have come across the R package `relaxo` by Meinshausen ([see here](https://stat.ethz.ch/~nicolai/relaxo.pdf)). However, as far as I can see this only applies to linear regressions.
So basically, are there packages that can do it for logistic regressions? And if not, can I just implement it myself by doing the first LASSO, saving the chosen predictors, and then do another LASSO on the same data/data frame, but with only the predictors chosen from the first LASSO, or is there more to it than that ?